# How to write a script to open a PDF file in Unity when image target is tracked?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I want to open a pdf file whenever my image target is tracked.
I know that if i want to open a pdf file with Unity i need to write this: `Application.OpenURL("file:///c:/filename.PDF");` but i want it to open only if the image target is tracked.

I think one possible way to solve this would be to change the DefaultTrackableEventHandler.cs so it will contain a boolean that will change when  tracking is found=true \ lost=false.

Anybody here know how to achieve this with Unity and Vuforia?Thanks guys

Comment: Can you share what this is for?

Comment: My idea is to create an app to generate a manual of instructions after the image is tracked by the user.It could be an png or jpg image too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DefaultTrackableEventHandler.cs you will find a function onTrackingFound()
add your code in this function and it will run whenever a target is found.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.But what if i only want it to display the pdf when a specific image target is tracked?

Comment: In function onTrackingFound(), put an if condition to check if it is your required target, if matches, show your PDF, else whatever you like to do with the rest of the targets. You can check your targets by name. Use mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName=="your_target_name_here" to check this condition.

Comment: Thank you so much Divyansh.I think this solves my problem.But i need to test it just to make sure.

Comment: I was wondering how could i set the correct path of the pdf file?The pdf file is in the assets/resources inside my project.i was thinking about putting like this : "C:\\Users\\Sansgung\\Desktop\\PitchPower\\PitchPower-Version2\\Assets\\Resources\\sample.pdf". But i don't think this should work outside my computer.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/Manual/StreamingAssets.html check this article for exact and detailed solution for file path of assets.

Comment: Thanks.You seem very good at this.Any chance you would be availabe for consultancy?I'm doing this all by myself and i would like someone to help me.If you are interested we can negociate an price.I work at a company specialized in augmented reality and we need people like you.

Comment: @gabriel sure, I can help you out. You can reach me through the information mentioned in my profile.